# cron for multiple stores in subdomains

Tags: multistore, cron

Do I need to copy the cron.php and cron.sh files into the subdomain of my second Magento store (running from the original installation) in order for sales emails to work for the second store?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, the main cron will do all.